# Jquery .on("click") doesn't work the second time

Tags: jquery

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs tabb">
        <li id="li_permission_info_<?=$this->id_permission?>" class="active" >
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_permission_info_<?=$this->id_permission?>"><i class="icon-user"></i>Permission Information <?=$this->id_permission?></a>
        </li>
        <li id="li_permission_details">
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_permission_details_<?=$this->id_permission?>" data-value="<?=$this->id_permission?>"><i class="icon-home"></i>Permission Details</a>
        </li>
</ul>
```

---

```
$("body").on("click", "#li_permission_details", function(event){

    console.log("test");

});
```

I'm having problem as the jquery script is not activated the second tim
e a click the `<li>` tag

Comment: You seem to have posted a script, rather than the generated HTML ('view source').

Comment: It is working fine mate. There maybe some problem with the rest of your code.

Comment: Are you sure that your not adding this "<?=$this->id_permission?>" to li_permission_detail id too?

Comment: The jQuery is fine, must be something else. Also, dont bind event do body if not needed :) Get the first #id wrapping #li_permission_details and use that as selector, and place the whole in a document ready (together with other `.on()`'s)

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward: No he doesnt, get gets bound to the li, not the anchor :)

Comment: works when using alert but using console.log it just display once

Comment: @DrixsonOseña: Even when using console.log it works fine for me. (I am using Opera/Chrome, if that is of any help/use).

Comment: @Harry, its not working to me... Just tested in fiddle using firefox

Comment: @Harry okay , whenever I click it i see it increments on console.log (1++)

Comment: just put your remaining script

Answer (score 3):

I have tried this code and this is working fine. Try this :

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs tabb">
         <li id="li_permission_info_<?=$this->id_permission?>" class="active" >
             <a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_permission_info_<?=$this->id_permission?>"><i class="icon-user"></i>Permission Information <?=$this->id_permission?></a>
         </li>
         <li id="li_permission_details">
             <a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_permission_details_<?=$this->id_permission?>" data-value="<?=$this->id_permission?>"><i class="icon-home"></i>Permission Details</a>
         </li>
      </ul>

      <script>
          $( "body" ).on( "click", "#li_permission_details", function() {
              alert('Hi');
          });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think somewhere in the code you are detaching the events...
I faced the same issue, somewhere in the code I used `$(document).off("click")`, which removed all the click events attached to the document.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem in your script. I made the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xQY3p/) for it and it is working fine. Stick the jq script inside the DOMReady event.

```
$("body").on("click", "#li_permission_details", function(event){
    alert("test");
});
```

Comment: I can click it for the first time, but on the second time it won't invoke the console.log

Comment: Please try the jsFiddle i posted earlier.

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine. To tune better instead of referring from body tag add a div id to the top of the link like below and try.

```
<div id="rajesh">Here your content</div>

$(#rajesh).on("click", "#li_permission_details", function(event){
    alert("Rajesh");
}
```

Running example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rajeshmepco/sXMdk/)

Comment: The last two lines of code were not showing up as code due to formatting error. I have formatted it now.